# Спрайт проваливается за пределы колайдера

Tags: unity3d-editor

Спрайт проваливается за пределы колайдера после начала работы аниматора. Я не понимаю почему робот не стоит на платформе, ведь у робота и платформы на которой он стоит есть Rigibody2D, но сам спрайт на половину смещается вниз относительно Rigibody2D...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемам была в неправильно сделанной анимации.